# Redirect 301 on Windows Server and ASPX

Tags: asp.net, windows, url, redirect

how can I redirect the URL of my old site from:

**http://www.example.com/*subdirectory/page.asp*?variable=value**

to

**http://www.example.com/page.*aspx*?variable=value**

Server Windows with

Comment: If your using Windows Server you can use IIS to do this. You can add the `Url Rewrite` extension and setup all of your redirections.

Comment: Ok, but one by one?

Comment: You can use regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

As i read :

"Url rewrite is one of the best and quickest ways to improve the usability and search friendliness of your site. It can also be the source of near-unending misery and suffering."

So be aware that if you do too much redirection... you'll mess everything up, make it simple.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Try to use regular expressions, and make the least number of redirection you can. The more you can do with a single redirection, the best it is.